# Did I prove correctly that $f:\mathbb E\to \mathbb N;\quad f(x)=\frac12 x$ is surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose we have two infinite sets, $\mathbb{N}$ (the set of natural numbers) and $\mathbb{E}$ (the set of even natural numbers). Give an example of a surjective function $\mathbb{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

$f:\mathbb{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{N};\quad f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$.

It is a surjection since $\frac{1}{2}x=y\implies\frac{1}{2}2x'=y\implies x'=y$ where $x=2x'$ and $x'\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is my argument correct? If so, is there anything I could improve?

Comment: Vague. It is a surjection since $f(2x)=x$ for *every* $x\in\mathbb N$, I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea, but it isn't very clear what you're doing until the end. I would start with an arbitrary $y\in\Bbb N.$ Then let $x=2y,$ and prove/note that $x\in\Bbb E.$ Then, note that $f(x)=y,$ and you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to show that the image of $f$ which is $x'$ is equal to the codomain $y$. Maybe I should write that $y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The problem is that $x'$ just shows up out of nowhere, with no explanation of what it is. Your approach is a good one for *calculating*, but not for proving. In a proof of surjecticity of $f,$, we have to show that for *every* $y$ in the given codomain of $f,$ there is at least one $x$ in the domain of $f$ for which $f(x)=y.$ If we're dealing with an infinite codomain, we obviously can't address each $y$ one at a time. Fortunately, in this instance, the same argument works for any $y\in\Bbb N,$ so there's no neex to split it into cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is not entirely correct. In proofs like this one, phrases like "**for all**" and "**there is**" are very important. As it is currently written, I would not actually say that we have a solid proof.

If you want to prove that $f$ is surjective, you must show/stress that **for all** $y\in\mathbb N$, **there is** an $x\in \mathbb E$, such that $f(x)=y$. Now argue that  $x=2y\,(\in\mathbb E)$ suffices and you're done.